Why does Leviticus 11 say that the rabbit chews the cud?
Leviticus 11 prescribes an illustrative list of animals which were unclean for Israelites

You may eat any animal that has a divided hoof and that chews the cud.
“‘There are some that only chew the cud or only have a divided hoof, but you must not eat them... The rabbit, though it chews the cud, does not have a divided hoof; it is unclean for you.

The breeds of rabbit we have today, do  not chew the cud. They however, keep their lips moving, which gives the impression that they are chewing the cud (Some new findings suggest that the rabbit eats its own poop for a second round of digestion). Is it possible that there were certain cud-chewing species of rabbit which are now extinct? Or, did the writer of Leviticus inadvertently mistake rabbit for a cud chewing animal?

Those ancient Levitical laws about clean and unclean animals contain many points that seem strange to us, but the one you raise actually gives rise to doubt about accuracy in the unambiguous claim of verse 5, namely, that the rabbit chews the cud.
However, the Study Bible below referred not to the rabbit, but to the coney, commenting on verse 5:

"coney - the old English name for rabbit." The Companion Bible,
p.147, Bullinger

Other translations speak of the hyrax in verse 5, noting, "The identification of some of the animals, birds and insects in this chapter is uncertain." It does not say 'rabbit' either. But in another footnote it says this:

"11:5-6  Neither the hyrax (or coney, or rock badger, or Syrian hyrax)
nor the hare truly chews the cud, though both appear to. They are
considered unclean because they do not have split hooves." New Living
Translation Study Bible, p.212, Tyndale Publishing

It may be reasonable to acknowledge that, when it came to visually identifying an animal that chewed its cud, a vegetarian beast sitting down for a length of time with its lower jaw visibly moving steadily the way cows do when chewing their cud, would suffice for identification. And both rabbits and hares give that appearance.
This might be a case where a more exact answer could come from posting this question in the Mi Yodea site on Stack.

Thanks, Anne. I feel that the list of unclean animals was prepared, keeping in view the continuance of foodchain. Human beings were allowed to eat the primary and secondary sources of energy . Rabbit was the natural prey of predators like fix and wolf. If human beings are up all the rabits, what would the fox eat ? Hence the listing of rabbit in the ' unclean' category.  Since the rabbit appeared to be chewing the cud, it would otherwise become a scandal for Non- Jews if Israel ate it . That reason meets the purpose ( to let chewing rabbits chew !)

PS: Spelling errors regretted. Please read ' fox' for 'fix ' and ' ate up' for ' are up'. Thanks.

My own theory on Leviticus ch11 is that it defines the normal diet of the nomadic herdsman (i.e flocks and herds), which would help to explain why crops are not mentioned. On that theory, part of the problem with rabbits is that they would have to be hunted.

Let me add to Anne's excellent answer.

Yet of those that chew the cud or have the hoof cloven you shall not
eat these: the camel, the hare, and the rock badger, because
they chew the cud but do not part the hoof, are unclean for you. -
Deuteronomy 14:7 ESV

First of all, Torah is not a treatise on Linnaean taxonomy, which standardized the naming and classification of living organisms into a hierarchy of groupings using Latin terms. Thus, a number of ancient Hebrew terms for animals have become obscure.
Here, Torah recognizes a distinction between lagomorphs and procavias. Having kept a variety of pets, I can assure you that rabbits have two types feces—a soft, greasy pellet called a cecotrope and a hard pellet. Lagomorphs re-ingest the soft pellets for secondary digestion, which analogous to the four-compartment stomachs and cud-chewing of ruminants such as sheep, cattle, and goats.
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/articles/Cecotrope
The hyrax, including the rock hyrax (Procavia habessinica), endemic to the Middle East, also has a multi-chambered digestive system (two in the stomach and two in the large intestine), which is not retrograde, and its observed chewing behavior is not associated with re-digestion.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8529006/
Incidentally, many people believe that some of the dietary guidelines in Torah are intended to prevent a number of serious parasites, infections, and diseases.
Lagomorphs in the wild can infect humans with tularemia, hepatic coccidiosis, rabies, and pasteurellosis.
https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/16/12/10-1013_article
Although the rock hyrax typically weighs a beefy nine pounds, it’s also a natural reservoir of a nasty protozoan, leishmania, which produces horrific-looking skin ulcers and can be life threatening to humans.
https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/24539-leishmaniasis

@+1. Excellent answer.  I am not always a fan of this site, but in this case it is helpful.  See https://answersingenesis.org/contradictions-in-the-bible/do-rabbits-really-chew-the-cud/

Thanks, Dottard. I appreciated the linked article. Regarding this forum, I agree with you, but I try to make it better when I can. Sometimes there interesting questions that challenge me do some research, resulting in my learning new things, and this is good. All the best!

@Dieter - I think Dottard meant answersingenesis.org as the site of which he is not always a fan.

Thanks, @Nephesh Roi, you may be right. The AiG articles tend to jump to conclusions too quickly rather than leaving some scientific issues unresolved, since it's the very nature of science to change its interpretations. However, my opinion of the BH forum is sincere. It seems like 80% of the questions here lately are questions of opinions involving general speculation rather than anything that can be addressed by hermeneutics. How would anyone know, for example, when Adam and Eve fell in love or whether they dated? Yes, I just made this one up.  :-)

I agree with you, Dieter, on both the issues.

I am confused by the emphasis in this discussion on the idea that the original writer believed a rabbit chewed it's cud simply because his mouth moves a lot.  The explanation given by AIG very clearly holds that the original Hebrew states, "A rabbit eats that which is brought forth again".  Rabbits are not ruminant but produce special fecal pellets called cecotropes which it redigests.  The Hebrew was translated into English (admittedly less precisely) as "chewing the cud". I fail to understand the purpose of seeking other explanations.  The original Hebrew seems accurate to me.
The AIG article:
https://answersingenesis.org/contradictions-in-the-bible/do-rabbits-really-chew-the-cud/
Thanks for considering.

Welcome to the BH forum, Todd. Be sure to take the tour: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour Also, you might want to read Anne's answer along with my addition. Kudos and +1 for checking the Hebrew. The Hebrew root of gerah (SH1625) is garar (SH1641), which is described as follows: "The Hebrew verb "garar" primarily means to drag or sweep away. It conveys the action of pulling or drawing something along, often with force or persistence."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. Todd We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Nature has a delicate balance which more often than not, is disturbed by human intervention. When Leviticus prescribed a list of clean and unclean animals, it had two purposes in mind : first to protect human beings from parasites and germs that spread through animals and secondly to give a thrust to ecological balance. I  always wondered what made those animals which chew the cud and have divided hooves apart-- until I watched some programmes on National Geographic. Animals that chew the cud survive on plants which are the primary source of energy. Since they tend to be attacked by predators while grazing, they gulp as much as they can, and have the intake digested when they reach a safe locality. Their split hooves help in easy movement on grassland, and in escaping the predators by taking quick turns, and if necessary by giving them a good hit with the leg.  Their amazing fecundity allowed fair balance of the population. Human beings were able to rear them for milk and meat .
Now, the rabbit has the habit of constantly moving its lower jaw which the human beings were likely to mistake for rumination. Since they were easily available in forests and fields, human beings hunted them, even digging them out of their otherwise secure den! Rabbits eat leafy vegetables on the ground. They were therefore helpful in weed control. So, Israelites had to be told that rabbits were not to be made extinct. The only visible sign  that would save the rabbit, was its un-split hooves which otherwise belonged to unclean animals. Hence the specific mention of rabbit in Leviticus.

Please consider adding references to your answer. For example, you wrote "Now, the rabbit has the habit of constantly moving its lower jaw which the human beings were likely to mistake for rumination." As someone who's familiar with rabbits, I would disagree with that statement. Rabbits do chew partially digested plant matter!

Thanks, Dieter. I have already included your point in my Question with link to an Irish article. That activity however does not translate into chewing the cud in the way cattle like cow do.
